# Parquet file is bigger after filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a parquet file in python with Pandas and I got a surprise.

The parquet file that I read weighs `290MB` and when I do a filtering to remove records from that dataframe and save it with `df.to_parquet()` I find that the new parquet weighs `390MB`

How can that be?

Here my code example:

```py
df = read_parquet('path/to/file.parquet')
ids_to_remove = ['id1','id2']

def filterout(df):
    return df[~df.id.isin(ids_to_remove)]

filtered_df = filterout(df)
filtered_df.to_parquet('path/to/save/filtered.parquet')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the filtering didn't remove any row from your file, but it may have changed some cells to be "bigger". For example, a **float** could have been changed from **5** to **5.0**.

Comment: Many thanks for your fast response @Hackjaku :) The thing is that I can see that it has indeed deleted those records...

Comment: Uhm, I'm guessing now, but can it be that there are so many cells that are increased so this overcompensate the deleted rows? You could try to check some sample rows to see if there is a noticeable difference.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I found...
Doing `df.info()` I realized that I had different index dtypes in both dataframes. This was causing the size differences...

How I solved it?
simple, just doing `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before saving the data.

I discovered this thanks to this entry: [python - Dataframes with RangeIndex vs.Int64Index - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566370/python-dataframes-with-rangeindex-vs-int64index-why)